Exchange server doesn't accept store command without explictely selecting the inbox
I have a ImapMailReceiver implementation to receive the emails from remote IMAP server, which works fine with any IMAP servers we tested so far. Nevertheless, one of the Exchange (2016) servers we have for our tests seems to not like the IMAP commands being sent to it while fetching the emails. Here is the list of commands, according to debug log, which are sent (without the auth part):
A3 LIST "" INBOX
* LIST (\Marked \HasChildren) "/" INBOX
A3 OK LIST completed.
A4 EXAMINE INBOX
* 15 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* FLAGS (\Seen \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Draft $MDNSent)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS ()] Permanent flags
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 14] UIDVALIDITY value
* OK [UIDNEXT 33765] The next unique identifier value
A4 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed.
A5 SEARCH NOT (FLAGGED) ALL
* SEARCH 1 6 7 9 10 11 13 14 15
A5 OK SEARCH completed.
A6 FETCH 1,6:7,9:11,13:15 (ENVELOPE INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE FLAGS BODYSTRUCTURE)
...
A6 OK FETCH completed.
A7 STORE 1 +FLAGS (\Flagged)
A7 NO Command received in Invalid state

As you can see it fails on the last command while setting the flag. Now, if I add the
SELECT INBOX

and then
A7 STORE 1 +FLAGS (\Flagged)

Everything works as expected. Apparently it's a weird Exchange server behaviour, but I wonder how can we fix the issue, by maybe somehow defining the list of commands being sent to server?

What is the error do you see from Spring perspective? Any thoughts what could be fixed in that ImapMailReceiver to satisfy such a requirements? Any chances that you can consult with that Exchange vendor to determine what is wrong from IMAP client perspective?

@ArtemBilan thnx for your response. Regarding the error, I am getting the following while calling receive() method: com.sun.mail.iap.CommandFailedException: A7 NO Command received in Invalid state.
We will definitely try to get in contact with Exchange support to investigate the issue from their side. And I also not sure how to workaround it from ImapMailReceiver perspective, I mean as a consumer I wouldn't like to manipulate actual IMAP commands being sent to the server.

@ArtemBilan in this particular case I'd assume something like setSelectFolder(true) which is then translated to appropriate SLECT [FOLDER] would help, but I am not sure how often such error appears (I guess not)

Sure! And how to initiate that select inbox from Java Mail client in our ImapMailReceiver? Feel free to contribute the fix!

Looks like there is a mail.imap.allowreadonlyselect = false Java Mail property: https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html

The AbstractMailReceiver has to be registered in the application context as a bean. It has a logic in its onInit():
@Override
protected void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    this.folderOpenMode = Folder.READ_WRITE;
    this.evaluationContext = ExpressionUtils.createStandardEvaluationContext(getBeanFactory());
}

This one is called by the BeanFactory for the InitializingBean hook. I'm not sure why the logic is like that, but I probably will into making this option modifiable from the target project.
Plus it looks like there is indeed a bug in Java DSL for mail where we don't initialize internally created ImapMailReceiver:
public static ImapIdleChannelAdapterSpec imapIdleAdapter() {
    return new ImapIdleChannelAdapterSpec(new ImapMailReceiver());
}

in opposed to:
public static ImapIdleChannelAdapterSpec imapIdleAdapter(ImapMailReceiver imapMailReceiver) {
    return new ImapIdleChannelAdapterSpec(imapMailReceiver, true);
}

where it's up to you to register it as a bean.

The '1' that you send is the number of that message in a mailbox, which isn't going to make a lot of sense to the server until you select a particular mailbox.
Spring issued examine inbox. The examine command selects a mailbox, read-only, which is enough for searching, as Spring does. If you want to set a flag, you need ① read-write access to the mailbox and ② the server must understand that when you say 1, you mean in that mailbox. The command select inbox does exactly that.

Thnx for your response. Can you please elaborate what exactly do you mean? Like having  STORE 10 +FLAGS (\Flagged) would make more sense? Even if it is, the command comes from ImapMailReceiver implementation and I have no control over it

I edited a bit.

So in other words, STORE 1, which is emitted by spring, assumes that inbox already in read-write mode, which isn't the case in case of our exchange server. SELECT INBOX basically enables the read-write mode, but we have no way to trigger such command as all the impl is behind the ImapMailReceiver. Did I get it right?

OK. The AbstractMailReceiver has a property folderOpenMode which is set to Folder.READ_WRITE in the onInit(). Do you register ImapMailReceiver as a bean, so its afterPropertiesSet() is called?

OK. The AbstractMailReceiver has a property folderOpenMode which is set to Folder.READ_WRITE in the onInit(). Do you register ImapMailReceiver as a bean, so its afterPropertiesSet() is called?

@ArtemBilan I think that was it, thank you very much. I did create the ImapMailReceiver instance manually (to be registered later via DSL) and adding afterPropertiesSet helps indeed. You can also format it as an answer here so I mark it as resolved
